# FB.ui() method does not work on Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-javascript-sdk, integration, facebook-php-sdk

I am facing a problem while working with Facebook SDK. I have Fb.ui() method which I am using for sharing the post in my application. The problem is that when I use the application on Desktop, it returns response after the Facebook has been shared which is the desired characteristic but in the case of Mobile, when the Pop-up opens, it immediately returns the response due to which I can't detect whether my post has been shared on Facebook or not? I have attached code below for further reference:

```
    Fb.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        display: isMobile() ? 'touch' : 'popup'
        link: hostUrl, 
    },function(response){
            if(isMobile()){
                if(response == '' || response.error_message){
                    console.log("Failure response from Mobile is ", response);      
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Successful response from Mobile is", response);
                }
            } else {
                if(response === '' || response.error_message){ //window closed
                    btn.classList.remove("share_disabled");
                    console.log("Failure response is ", response);
                    sendLogFB("FBShare desktop WINDOW action : closed");
                } else {
                    console.log("Successful response is ", response);
                }
            }
    });
```

I tried many methods and none of that works.

Comment: What for do you need to "detect" this? (I hope you are aware that _rewarding_ users for sharing in any way, is not allowed to begin with - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-developer-policy-3.2)

Comment: I have to take appropriate actions in response to if the user posts on the Facebook and the post sharing is successful. I am able to do this on Desktop, but on mobile, it is not working.

Comment: And that "appropriate action" would be what, exactly?